# How to add Java System Runtime Parameters?

Tags: windows-7, java

I'm given the following instructions:

> You must set the sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax system property
>   to true by adding the following to the JVM arguments:
>
> -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

How do I do that?  I go here:

[image]

But I cannot edit the Runtime Parameters in the System tab. And even on the Users tab, it will not save my changes.  I need this to be a system-wide change.

I ran the Java Control Panel by Right-clicking it and choosing Run as Administrator. I'm full admin on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click the 'Runtime Parameters' box in the *USER* side and edit it there.

These changes will get propagated to the *SYSTEM* side.

Please don't ask me why, I don't want to consider the ramifications.

Comment: Sure enough... I see the same behavior. I'm not sure Oracle really gets the distinction between user and system...

Answer (score 1):

edit `"%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"`

records `... .args=`

```
notepad "%APPDATA%\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"
```